# Creating lists in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Wasn't really sure how else to word the title, but here's a little more information!

In this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oXLbc9vkjuWYU60xhsYsT3vv7utOJswVjwJUWS3XpF0/edit?usp=sharing

In the 'Lists by Item Type' sheet, I would like to make lists of all the items separated by item types for use in data validation elsewhere. Is there a function similar to `=UNIQUE()` that will give me a list of all items with the value `x` in column Q where `x` is the item type I input?

Comment: I think I did what you want: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KXpn0Brv8QvlmVe0wYw2TNDJeAcJI_5IUbWk6g86LJk/edit#gid=660121919

Comment: @trinalbadger587, its telling me I need access make sure to set the sharing properly please!!

Comment: Alright, so the `join` function isn't going to work, because I need it as a range of cells for data validation >.< that was the first thing I thought of

Comment: I overlooked that, my bad! That'll work perfectly!

Comment: This is just nitpicky, but is there a way to make it go down a column instead of across?

Comment: Just take out the TRANSPOSE(

Comment: I've been following along as you go, that is exactly what I need, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```js
=FILTER(
    /* all item names ('Item Database'!$A$3:$A) */,
    /* all item types ('Item Database'!$Q$3:$Q) */ = /* the needed item type */
)
```

This will give you all the items of a given type.

Comment: I marked this as answered, but I do have one more question if you might be so inclined to continue helping, how would I turn up a list of everything NOT Armor OR Weapons. I know if I put `<>"Weapon"` for example, it'll give me a list of everything not a weapon, but what if I need both as the criteria?

Comment: Disregard above, did some reading on the `FILTER` function and answered my own question ^~^ `=FILTER(range, condition 1, [condition 2], ...)` you can add more conditions to the filter as you need